# Should mscorlib's FileInfo.MoveTo() throw an exception if trying to move a file to itself? Will this change in the future?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mscorlib

Microsoft's documentation for FileInfo.MoveTo(string destination) claims that an exception is thrown if the destination file already exists: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto(v=vs.110).aspx

As I just discovered, however, calling FileInfo.MoveTo() and inputting the location that the file is currently sitting in does *not* throw the exception. This occurs on Windows 7, .Net 4, Visual Studio 2012.

A quick google search didn't show me any discussion of this behavior. Does anyone know if it's considered a bug and will be changed at some point?

Edit: File.Move() does the same thing.

Comment: Imo it's not a real bug but a lack of documentation. If they would ever change this behaviour they'd break a lot of code for no reason. Moving a file to itself is a no-op.

Comment: The current implementation in the BCL dips right into Win32's underlying `MoveFile()` API which is similarly documented & exhibits the same behaviour (and likely would have done so going back into ancient history). Personally I can't see this ever being changed.

Comment: No exception specifications in neither .NET nor the OS you run on.  The file system driver is going to get sulky when you try to overwrite a *different* file with the same name.  Which will happen when the destination directory or drive is different.  A simple counter-measure against accidental data loss.

Comment: Moving a file to itself is expressly permitted. That's how you rename a file to change case.